# JS create safe get function without using strings

Tags: javascript, typescript

In Lodash, for example, there is the `get` function where you can do this:

```
_.get(object, 'a[0].b.c');
// => 3

_.get(object, ['a', '0', 'b', 'c']);
// => 3

_.get(object, 'a.b.c', 'default');
```

My problem with this approach is that when I work with typescript, it does not protect me from typos. I am trying to create a similar functionality without passing strings.

```
const obj = {a: {b: {c: {}}}, b: {}};

const a = get(obj, obj => obj.a.b.c.d.g, 'defaultValue');


function get(obj: T, getFn, defaultValue) {
  try {
    return getFn(obj);
  } catch(err) {
    return defaultValue;
  }
}
```

This is the right way to do it? Or there is a better approach?

Comment: You might consider the [optional chaining proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining) which would allow you to do `obj?.a?.b?.c?.d?.g` without a `try`/`catch`, assuming you use [babel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-optional-chaining).

Comment: You missed a scenario in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how safe you want to make the function,  I would also specify the type of `getFn` and constrain the `defaultValue` to be the same as the result og `getFn`

```
const obj = { a: { b: { c: { d: { g: '1' }} } }, b: {} };

function get<T, TResult>(obj: T, getFn: (o: T) => TResult, defaultValue: TResult) {
    try {
        let result =  getFn(obj);
        return result == undefined ? defaultValue : result;
    } catch (err) {
        return defaultValue;
    }
}


const aa = get(obj, obj => obj.a.b.c.d.g, 'defaultValue');
get({ x: 0 }, o => o.x, 'defaultValue'); // Compiler Error, x is number, default is string
get({ x: 0 }, o => o.x, 0); // Ok, same result  type
get({ x: { y : 1} }, o => o.x.yy, 0); // Compiler Error, Catches property typos as well
```

Comment: It's not a ts types question, but thanks for that. It's more about the try catch approach. Do you think this is the best approach?

Comment: @undefined, wops, I assumed that it was, when you have a hammer everything is a nail :). I think the approach is ok, as long as you expect the property access to succeed most of the time.

Comment: Marked as the answer because this is both types and js solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your current code with fail if the structure of `obj` is like

```
{a: {b: {c: { d: {} }}}, b: {}}
```

In that case, your code would've returned undefined. You need to return a default value in the `try` block too, like this:

```
const obj = {a: {b: {c: { d: {} }}}, b: {}};

const a = get(obj, obj => obj.a.b.c.d.g, 'defaultValue');


function get(obj: T, getFn, defaultValue) {
  try {
    let val = getFn(obj);  
    if(val === null || val === undefined) { // SEE HERE
      return defaultValue;
    }
    return val;
  } catch(err) {
    return defaultValue;
  }
}
```

Comment: That will also return `defaultValue` if the object had `d: { g: 0 }`, you probably want a stricter check than a standard `falsy || ` for a function like this. Maybe store the result of `getFn(obj)` in a variable and test if it's `undefined`.

Comment: true, edited the answer to check for null and undefined